# Presale wallet gives zero funds

Tags: ether, accounts, presale, recovery, access

I have already asked this question but I post once again as helpdesk people at ethereum are asking to post here:

After several years of waiting, I have decided to check how much ether I do have in my presale wallets. As I checked one of them with the address: 31680d74c182be56e3c122e37f3584ca480d528d

I am getting: No free outputs to spend.

The wallets were in a hidden location, encrypted. I haven't used them so far.

I would be thankful in case you can clarify this issue because then I would have lost my bitcoins which I used for this wallet.

Comment: Your presale wallet file also was emailed to you, so check there. Look for the file called "ethereum_wallet_backup.json" and select that file. This wallet file will be encrypted with a password that you created during the purchase of the pre-sale.

Comment: The thing is that during the crowdfunding I received several wallets. Among them, the only one that is not working is this wallet.

Comment: Related [meta discussion](https://ethereum.meta.stackexchange.com/q/426/87).

Comment: Of course but this is why I posted here: There is no initial balance, nothing.

What I copied & pasted is the ether address in the json file. I copy & paste the exact entry: ethaddr":"31680d74c182be56e3c122e37f3584ca480d528d"

I used this link https://ethereum.org/ether#balance but also imported using Mist; it gave 0 ethers.

Comment: Hi @developer12, did you ever get access to your wallet? Just curious because you are actually one of several going through this issue right now, including myself.

Answer (score 2):

This doesn't appear to be your correct address. I checked on [etherscan](https://etherscan.io/address/0x31680d74c182be56e3c122e37f3584ca480d528d) and it shows no transactions in this address at all. A valid presale address should show the initial balance plus any subsequent transactions.

Your presale wallet should be a json file, secured by a passphrase. You can import that into an Ethereum wallet such as [MyEtherWallet](https://www.myetherwallet.com/) or Parity. If you have both of those, you should be all set. Unless you bought an insignificant amount, it'd be best to do this on an offline computer.

The phrase "no free outputs" sounds like you're putting this address into a bitcoin client; Ethereum doesn't have a concept of "outputs" the way Bitcoin does, it's just an account with a balance.

I got to wondering whether you're checking the bitcoin address that you used to buy your presale ether, but there don't appear to be any bitcoin transactions for this [address](https://blockchain.info/address/15WEm6iMPt1DLxvYh7Qbba9mEaZckmc3C1) either.

Comment: Of course but this is why I posted here: There is no initial balance, nothing.
I have a json file which is like the others. What I copied & pasted is the ether address in the json file. I copy & paste the exact entry: ethaddr":"31680d74c182be56e3c122e37f3584ca480d528d"

I used this link https://ethereum.org/ether#balance but also imported using Mist; it gave 0 ethers.

Comment: I haven't heard of this happening before. I'd say contact the Ethereum Foundation, using the email link near the bottom of the ethereum.org homepage.

Comment: I contacted them but no replies. So now what should I do?